# Haskell - How to define the dependent type Remainder (i.e. Rmndr modulo)?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

My understanding is that the remainder type is a dependent type (depending on the modulo). I read about the DataKinds extension and was able to define it like the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, GADTs #-}
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

data Rmndr modulo where
    Nil :: Rmndr Zero
    Rmndr :: Integer -> Rmndr modulo
```

But then when I preceeded to implement the Eq class, I stuck at the condition

```
Rmndr x == Rmndr y = (x `mod` modulo) == (y `mod` modulo)
```

because modulo is not a value, but a type. Even if we can write a function as follow:

```
decat :: Nat -> Integer
decat Zero = 0
decat (Succ nat) = decat nat + 1
```

we cannot use it as follows

```
instance Eq (Rmndr modulo) where
    Nil == Nil = True
    Rmndr x == Rmndr y =
        x `mod` (decat modulo) == y `mod` (decat modulo)
```

because "modulo" in this syntax is not a variable.

Can any one help on this puzzle? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use a typeclass to associate each natural number type with a **singleton** value. We do this by creating an instance for `Zero` associating with `0` and a recursive instance for `Succ x`. To access the type itself, we need to take a dummy proxy argument. The idiom for proxy arguments is to use a type variable called `proxy a`; when you go to call this, you would most often use `Proxy` from `Data.Proxy`.

Here's the relevant class:

```
class SingNat n where
  sing :: proxy n -> Integer
```

and the instances:

```
instance SingNat Zero where sing _ = 0

instance SingNat n => SingNat (Succ n) where
  sing _ = 1 + sing (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

To make all of this work, you also have to enable `ScopedTypeVariables` which ensures the `n` in `:: Proxy n` is the same as the one in `SingNat (Succ n)`.

A good intuition here is that the two typelcass instances are like the two cases of your `decat` function, but at the typelevel. Typeclasses used like this function as a little typelevel logic programming language, not unlike a mini Prolog.

Now you can use `sing` to get the modulo bound in your definition of `Eq` (and elsewhere):

```
instance SingNat n => Eq (Rmndr n) where
  Rmndr x == Rmndr y = (x `mod` modulo) == (y `mod` modulo)
    where modulo = sing (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

This sort of code is a great way to get the hang of type level programming. However, in real code, you probably don't want to roll your own natural number type because GHC has one built-in with `DataKinds`. Apart from being standard, this also gives you some syntax sugar at the type level letting you write types like `Rmndr 10`. If you're curious about this approach, take a look at my [modular-arithmetic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic) package, which implements your reminder type but using the built-in type level numbers and some nicer syntax. The code is short, so just read the source.

Comment: Just a note: you can't really do induction with the built in type level naturals, because arithmetic is done with type families, which are non-injective, and you end up not being able to convince the typechecker of very obvious things. This particular application is well suited for type nats because no induction is required.

Comment: @user2407038: Ah, good point. My own uses also didn't need induction, so it didn't come to mind. I have run into other cases where I couldn't convince it of very obvious things though :).

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the detailed answer! I am still digesting the source code of modular-arithmetic and might come up with more questions. Thanks!

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: I am confused by the line #81 in your module. `code` instance (Read i, Integral i, KnownNat n) => Read (i `Mod` n)
  where readsPrec prec = map (first toMod) . readsPrec prec
`code`. First, since the toMod has not been implemented as an instance of Arrow, how does "first" make sense; second, I am always confused by the readsPrec function - seems a cyclic definition (left side and right side both use the same function with same argument). Please help. Thanks!

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Another question about the Arrow class - in the function "first", where comes the class variable "d" on the right side?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: OK. Now I understand the "first" - considering "->" as an Arrow type. So the only thing I do not understand is how "(10 :: (Int/3))" can be parsed by the system - since there is no Read instance for the "3" type defined in GHC.TypeLits. The Read instance SomeNat, as I understand, cannot parse the string " (10 :: (Int/3)) ".

Comment: @xiphoid: `read` only determines how to parse things from a string, not how the compiler parses normal code. Indeed, `read "10 :: (Int/3)"` would not work, but that's the desired behavior. `readsPrec` is implemented in terms of `readsPrec` for the underlying type (ie `Int` or `Integer`); I just read one of those and then apply `toMod` to it.

Comment: @xiphoid: Also, if you have any more questions, just post them as a GitHub issue or email me; using StackOverflow comments for this is a bit awkward.